# calculating DFT of time signal in MATLAB

Tags: fft, dft, continuous-fourier

This code computes the DFT from time domain.
Can anybody see the code below and help me to get the right answer?
my problem is:
when I change N value, for example, to 4, 5, 10 ,or other values.
X(1) changes with that. but I think X(1) must be the same for every value of N.
just like the shape below: the N value changes but the vertical value is the same.
I appreciate if you help me.
Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qycoc.png)

```
clear; clc;
% %%  Analytical
N=4;
k=0:N-1;
X=zeros(N,1);
t=k/N;
x=(5+2*cos(2*pi*t-pi/2)+3*cos(4*pi*t))
%x=abs((1-(0.012.*(pi.*52.*(t-0.3721)).^2)).*exp(-(pi.*52.*(t-0.3721).^2)))
abs(sum(x))

for k=0:N-1
    for n=0:N-1
        X(k+1)=X(k+1)+x(n+1).*exp(-1i.*2.*pi.*(n).*(k)/N);
    end
end

k1=[0:N-1];
stem(k1,abs(X))
% xlim([0 1])
% ylim([-1 1])
xlabel('Frequency');
ylabel('|X(k)|');
title('Frequency domain - Magnitude response')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of DFT (which is probably the most common definition) does not have the property that `X(1)` remains constant with N. Instead, it is `X(1)/N` which will remain constant. To use this DFT to get the magnitudes of the input at various frequencies, you'll need to divide the DFT output by `N`.

To verify this, you can call Matlab's `fft` function and compare with your results. You should get the same answer from Matlab's `fft`. Note that Matlab's [fft documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/discrete-fourier-transform.html) says:

> The resulting FFT amplitude is A*n/2, where A is the original amplitude and n is the number of FFT points.